# Oracle SQL script running from Linux command line with alter session

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, datetime, date-formatting

We have a Java app that will remotely query all the SQL files in a directory and output the CSV files. It works great if the SQL files have just the SELECT command. However, in order to get the datetimes in the right format, I want to use the ALTER session command. This produces an error in the Java app as it treats each command as a new file. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the code base of the Java app. Essentially, the SQL files each look like the following:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'; 

SELECT * from sample_table
```

Is there any way to run the edit a SQL file to run as a single executed query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';` is a DDL statement. You cannot execute that as a DML statement. Your Java Statement class won't work to execute this ALTER SESSION ... query.

Moreover, if talking from the Database connection perspective, it is valid only up to that session in which it is applied, next time it won't hold still the same value.

This change can't be made permanently using this approach, there is a different approach, which is off-topic here (I know because once I also felt the same need, but came to know the things after struggling for a few days).

The way how you're trying to achieve your result is incorrect.

**Format the content into whatever format you want your date-time to be displayed in**, you don't need an ALTER SESSION command alongwith a SELECT query.

Use `to_char(yourDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as customDate` and try adjusting to your main select query.

Comment: the datetime fields in the table only output as mm/dd/yyyy if I don't use the alter session command. How can I make the select query force the full datetime with hours, mins, and seconds also included?

Comment: @Marc - Edited to make it clear, check the last line.

Comment: Ok this will display the datetimes for me in the output correctly. So just to be clear in the WHERE statement, even though the display is just showing mm/dd/yyyy, any comparisons that I do with datetimes are actually going down to the second (eg. comparing one datetime greater than another one)? The only thing that altering the session does is how it will be displayed?

Comment: @Marc - Didn't get any single point, except for the last one! `The only thing that altering the session does is how it will be displayed?` -> YES. Please reframe the other questions. I don't see any WHERE statement in the original post/question.

Comment: Sorry. I guess I don't completely understand what setting nls_date_format does. Will datetime comparisons (in a WHERE clause) function the EXACT same whether it is set to 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' or 'YYYY-MM-DD'? In essence, is it purely for how the output will be displayed?

Comment: @Marc - From [oracle's](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm#REFRN10119) online reference, `NLS_DATE_FORMAT specifies the default date format to use with the TO_CHAR and TO_DATE functions. ` Regarding the second point, YES, if you compare 2 date format, if both are in same format, they would work correctly irrespective of nls_date_format setting.

Comment: Ah. You are helpful!

Comment: When I just do "select dt_variable from sample_table", is that automatically a TO_CHAR behind the scenes? Before the NLS_DATE_FORMAT edit, it does it as 'yyyy-mm-dd', but after i change it, it goes to include hours/mins/seconds.

Comment: @Marc - No, it is not. It is still a date-format value. Though you may be seeing it in the form of a string, but, even the ints get displayed like a regular string. I hope you got my point. Regarding the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT `, once again I repeat it just formats the way you see your date-value.